# UITabBarController rotation problem with popViewControllerAnimated and selectedIndex (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, selectedindex, popviewcontroller

This is a very important auto rotate issue and easy to reproduce.

My application has a UITabBarController. Each tab is a UINavigationController. Auto rotation is handled with normal calls to shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation.

The interface rotates normally until I call UIViewController.popViewControllerAnimated and change UITabBarController.selectedIndex.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a demo Tab Bar Application.
2. Add the following code to the App Delegate .h file:

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @interface TestRotationAppDelegate : NSObject  {
       UIWindow *window;
       UITabBarController *tabBarController;
   }

   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

   @end

   // Redefine the interface to cach rotation messages
   @interface UITabBarController (TestRotation1AppDelegate)

   @end
   ```
3. Add the following code to the App Delegate .m file:

   ```
   #import "TestRotationAppDelegate.h"

   @implementation TestRotationAppDelegate
   @synthesize window;
   @synthesize tabBarController;

   -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
       [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
       [window makeKeyAndVisible];
       return YES;
   }

   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
       return YES;
   }

   -(void)dealloc {
       [tabBarController release];
       [window release];
       [super dealloc];
   }

   @end

   @implementation UITabBarController (TestRotation1AppDelegate)

   -(void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       // Add a third tab and push a view 
       UIViewController *view1 = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
       view1.title = @"Third";
       UINavigationController *nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view1] autorelease];
       NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       [array addObjectsFromArray:self.viewControllers];
       [array addObject:nav];
       self.viewControllers = array;
       // Push view2 inside the third tab
       UIViewController *view2 = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
       [nav pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
       // Create a button to pop view2
       UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
       button.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 220, 38);
       [button setTitle:@"Pop this view" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [button addTarget:self action:@selector(doAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       [view2.view addSubview:button];
   }

   -(void) doAction {
       // ROTATION PROBLEM BEGINS HERE
       // Remove one line of code and the problem doesn't occur.
       [self.selectedViewController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
       self.selectedIndex = 0;
   }

   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
       return YES;
   }

   @end
   ```

The interface auto rotates normally until you tap the button on tab #3.

Your help will be geatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone SDK 3.2 solves this issue.

With previous SDK use [self.selectedViewController popViewControllerAnimated:NO].